# Transmission interrupt in PIC18F46K80

Tags: pic, uart, interrupts

I'm using a [PIC18F46K80](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/30509a-1314245.pdf) and have been trying to send data to the computer using USART module (simulating in Proteus). This is my code:

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000
#define RED_LED 49

#include <xc.h>
#include "Config.h"

//USART variables
char clks = 0, sync = 0, brgh = 1, brg16 = 0;

//USART init

void USART_init() {
    //I/O Config
    TRISCbits.TRISC7 = 1; //Config RX as input
    TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 0; //Config TX as output

    TXSTA1bits.CSRC = clks; //Clock Source Select bit
    TXSTA1bits.SYNC = sync; //EUSARTx Mode Select bit
    TXSTA1bits.BRGH = brgh; //High Baud Rate Select bit
    TXSTA1bits.TXEN = 1; //Transmit Enable bit

    RCSTA1bits.CREN = 1; //Enable Continuous Receive mode
    RCSTA1bits.SPEN = 1; //Enable Serial Port

    BAUDCON1bits.BRG16 = brg16; //16-Bit Baud Rate Register

    SPBRG1 = 25; //19200 Baud rate
}

void interrupt_init() {
    PIE1bits.TX1IE = 1; //Transmit interrupt bit enabled
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1; //Global interrupt enabled
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; //Peripheral interrupt enabled
}

void main() {
    TRISD = 0;
    TRISA = 0;
    
    USART_init(); //USART configuration
    interrupt_init(); //Interrupt configuration

    while (1) {
        LATDbits.LATD5 = ~LATDbits.LATD5;
        __delay_ms(500);
    }
}

void __interrupt() ISR() {
    INTCONbits.GIE = 0; //Disable global interrupt
        if (PIR1bits.TX1IF == 1) { //If transmit interrupt flag is set
        LATDbits.LATD6 = ~LATDbits.LATD6;
        __delay_ms(200);
    }
    PIR1bits.TX1IF = 0; //Reset transmit flag
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1; //Disable global interrupt
}
```

And the problem is that, once the code goes into the infinite loop, the interrupt function is called over and over which means the rest of the code in the infinite loop don't have the time to run.

If any information is needed which I didn't include, please let me know.

Comment: Don't use time consuming, delay based functions (like that LCD functions) in interrupt service routines.

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad That doesn't help me really, but thanks  for the advice.

Comment: @Momo - Welcome :-) This site is quite different from typical forums, and has its own rules. For example: (a) Your sarcastic comment was deleted. All site members are required to comply with the [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct). Failure to comply can lead to the sanctions in the "Enforcement" section, near the bottom of that page. Please *be nice*. (b) As also mentioned in the CoC (and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120576) on Meta.SE) having other users edit a Q or A to improve readability is normal on Stack Exchange e.g. adding a datasheet link in your Q. Any questions?

Comment: [Continued] Also [this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) in the [help] shows what you can do, if you are not getting the answers you are hoping for.

Comment: @SamGibson Sorry about the sarcastic comment, but I wasn't being rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a process is stuck in the ISR, there are a few reasons:

- **There is a non-terminated code in the ISR.** just like a loop. that's unlikely because everyone familiar with the concept of an interrupt avoids that.
- **The "thing" that invoked the ISR is not cleared.** some peripheral interrupts don't clear their flag automatically. we have to clear the flag "according to a procedure, if any, described by datasheet".
- **The ISR itself consumes so much time, that as soon it is over, another interrupt activates.** for example, using delay based functions in RX ISR. with a baudrate of 9600, a device receives a byte once every ~1ms and an interrupt would be invoked with that period. if your code wastes more than 1ms, you gonna miss the data, and the code in your while loop.

---

Your problem seems to be the second and third items described above. the datasheet mentions:

> Once the TXREGx register transfers the data to the TSR register
> (occurs in one TCY), the TXREGx register is empty and the TXxIF flag
> bit is set. This interrupt can be enabled or disabled by setting or
> clearing the interrupt enable bit, TXxIE. TXxIF will be set regardless
> of the state of TXxIE; **it cannot be cleared in software.**

But in your last line of code, you are trying to clear it manually. It won't; it can be cleared only by writing a data to the TXREG to be transferred. so you are stuck in the immediately-repeating ISR.

The time-wasting functions in your ISR are not a problem for this particular code, but are prohibited anyway; It's not a good practice to use delay based functions (like that LCD functions in the code before edit). The interrupt concept is like an SMS to main application. Application does not like its SMS notification sound, last 20 seconds like a phone call; A brief "ding" would suffice.

Code example to transmit some bytes (self explanatory):

```
unsigned char buff_index, tx_buffer_max;
unsigned char *tx_buffer;
bool tx_trans_complete;

void uart_transmit_buffer(unsigned char *buffer, unsigned char data_length)
{
    buff_index = 0;
    tx_buffer_max = data_length;
    tx_buffer = buffer;
    tx_trans_complete = false;
    //enable the interrupt for TX. as the TXREG is empty, an interrupt would happen
    PIE1bits.TX1IE = 1;
}

void __interrupt() ISR() {
    if (PIR1bits.TX1IF == 1) 
    { //If transmit interrupt flag is set
        TXREG1 = tx_buffer[buff_index];
        buff_index++;
        if(buff_index == tx_buffer_max)
        {
            PIE1bits.TX1IE = 0; //disable the interrupt enable bit
            tx_trans_complete = true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
void main(void)
{
    //INIT YOUR PERIPHS
    unsigned char boom_boom_buff[13] = "boom boom SE";
    uart_transmit_buffer(boom_boom_buff,13);
    //wait or do other stuff till tx_trans_complete = true;
    //...
    //...
    if(tx_trans_complete)
    {
        //we have transfered that boom boom thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer, I really enjoyed the hints and the way you code. As the datasheet says so 
>>Enable the transmission by setting bit, TXEN,
which will also set bit, TXxIF
So basically, as soon I enable global and Peripheral interrupt and transmission, interrupt function will automatically start, and not even resetting the flag can stop this process. which means I only have to enable the transmission interrupt (PIE1bits.TX1IE = 1) whenever I need to send a data.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember my PIC programming correctly, you have to clear the condition that caused the interrupt before you reset the interrupt flag.  Otherwise, the condition will set the interrupt flag again. Try putting your commands that reset flags, like PIR1bits.RC1IF = 0; as the last command enclosed in the IF statement instead of the first.

Same with PIR1bits.TX1IF = 0;  command.

Comment: The datasheet says that:
>Enable the transmission by setting bit, TXEN,
which will also set bit, TXxIF<
(TXEN = Transmit Enable bit) So basically once you set the Transmission enable bit, the interrupt is activated.
Does this mean I have to set TXEN whenever I need it and reset once i'm done with it?

Comment: @Momo Yes. (It's only for telling you that the 1-byte TX buffer is empty and ready for another byte, should you want to continue sending.)